# How should I properly initialize a C struct from C++?

Tags: c++, cross-platform, initialization

I have the following code in a C++ file:

```
#include <sys/socket.h>

// ...
void someFunc() {
    struct msghdr msg = {0};  // <<< Uninitialized member here
}
```

When I compile with `g++` using `-Wall -Wextra`, I get warnings:

```
error: missing initializer for member 'msghdr::msg_namelen'
...same for several other fields
```

My problem is this: I can't explicitly initialize all the fields, because I don't know what fields will exist (cross-platform) in a `struct msghdr`. The struct doesn't have a default constructor, since it's a C struct. I was under the impression that the `= {0}` form led to zero-initialization of all fields (which would be fine for me), but the `g++` error message suggests not.

What are my options here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is the compiler throwing this warning: "missing initializer"? Isn't the structure initialized?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538943/why-is-the-compiler-throwing-this-warning-missing-initializer-isnt-the-stru)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Do this:

```
void someFunc()
{
    msghdr msg = {};  // <<< All members zero-initialized
}
```

The g++ `-Wextra` warning level is IMHO not very useful.

The code that you have is also formally OK for a "C struct", in standardeese known as [POD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_data_structure) (plain old data structure). But your code explicitly initializes the first member with 0. That won't necessarily work for an aggregate that isn't POD, e.g., with a `std::string` as the first member, while the pure `{}` will work also for that.

In passing, often a POD like the one you're dealing with has a byte count as the first member, and then you can do like …

```
void foo()
{
    SomePODStruct o = {sizeof(o)};    // The other members zero-initialized.
}
```

Perhaps add a `STATIC_ASSERT` that the byte count member is first (at offset 0).

Comment: I don't agree with the sentence _The g++ -Wextra warning level is not very useful_.

Comment: @peoro: OK. I added an "IMHO". :-)

Comment: Skipping `=` is also  ok: https://godbolt.org/z/8fzxbczrY

Answer (score 4):

This should work:

```
memset(&msg, 0, sizeof(msg));
```

Comment: fix your typo and I'll remove my answer, you beat me to it by seconds! :)

Comment: I hate `memset`. It is bug prone (easy to use wrong order of arguments) and verbose. It is not C++sy and even in this case using C proper use of braces does the job: https://godbolt.org/z/7zf6fKvKn

Answer (score 2):

The specific warning flag that causes this is [-Wmissing-field-initializers](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wmissing-field-initializers), which is turned on as part of [-Wextra](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wextra). The simplest way to avoid this (bogus) warning is therefore to use [-Wno-missing-field-initializers](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wmissing-field-initializers).

Answer (score 1):

If you can't live with the warning and/or don't want to disable the warning, then I think it will have to be explicit initialisation via e.g. memset:

```
memset(&msg, 0, sizeof(msg));
```