# How to neatly initialize struct tm from ctime

Tags: c++, c++11, ctime

Consider these two ways to get an epoch time from a date formatted as a string:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    struct tm tm_init = {0};
    strptime("2012-10-26 16:00", "%Y-%m-%dT %H:%M", &tm_init);
    long epoch = mktime(&tm_init);

    struct tm tm_rand;
    strptime("2012-10-26 16:00", "%Y-%m-%dT %H:%M", &tm_rand);
    epoch = mktime(&tm_rand);

    return 0;
}
```

Source: http://ideone.com/3xMUm8 . Essentially the difference is that tm_init is initialized with 0 and tm_rand is not. The first one triggers g++ (assuming -Wall and -W) to say:

```
test.cpp:4:24: warning: missing initializer for member ‘tm::tm_hour’ [-Wmissing-field-initializers]
```

and similar messages for other fields in the tm struct. However, if I leave out the initialization, like in the second case, valgrind tells me:

```
==9892== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==9892==    at 0x51E957C: __offtime (offtime.c:40)
==9892==    by 0x51EBBE7: __tz_convert (tzset.c:653)
==9892==    by 0x51E9EDB: __mktime_internal (mktime.c:310)
==9892==    by 0x400786: main (test.cpp:10)
```

Of course, the latter is way worse than the first, but I don't like warnings either. Of course, I can initialize all the fields manually, by writing some kind of tm factory; but that would require me to write code depending on the logic of mt, and I would need two write a factory (blegh).

Is this a bug in ctime? Unfortunately I could not find (semi-)official documentation on strptime, that is, there is no cplusplus.com page on it. Am I missing something? WHat is the *good* way to parse a string to an epoch long?

**EDIT:**

As suggested by some answers, I should set the tm_isdst manually to -1, 0 or 1. However this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    struct tm tm;
    strptime("2012-10-26 16:00", "%Y-%m-%dT %H:%M", &tm);
    tm.tm_isdst = 0;
    long epoch = mktime(&tm);
    return 0;
}
```

Results in valgrind saying this:

```
==11329== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==11329==    at 0x51E9917: __offtime (offtime.c:83)
==11329==    by 0x51EBBE7: __tz_convert (tzset.c:653)
==11329==    by 0x51EA513: __mktime_internal (mktime.c:310)
==11329==    by 0x40078D: main (test.cpp:7)
```

So, should I also set _offtime?

Comment: Official documentation: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strptime.html . cplusplus.com is most certainly *not* official, and is considered a poor reference by many on this site.

Comment: Related: [Why do I get “warning: missing initializer for member”? -Wmissing-field-initializers](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21658485/341970)

Comment: It looks like a bug to me: Neither clang, nor gcc warns about the uninitialized `tm tm_rand` although I think they should. I will check this with the latest gcc and clang and if the problem still exists, submit a bug report.

Comment: @Ali, sorry for not posting this as a bug report then :) I'm always very reluctant in filing a bug report because I'm never really sure I'm right. Please keep me updated about what seems to be the problem, also if it is pebkac.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the official documentation of [`strptime`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strptime.html):

```
struct tm tm;
time_t t;
strptime("6 Dec 2001 12:33:45", "%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S", &tm);
tm.tm_isdst = -1;      /* Not set by strptime(); tells mktime()
                          to determine whether daylight saving time
                          is in effect */
t = mktime(&tm);
```

So you should be setting `tm_rand.tm_isdst = -1` to tell `mktime` to check DST from the locale.  Alternatively you can set it to `0` or `1`.

It's unfortunate that the official documentation doesn't explicitly say that `tm_isdst` is left unset, but at least it's mentioned in the example.

Comment: As you suggested, I've set  tm_isdst to 0, which also leads to unset members of tm: in particular _offtime. Moreover, in my real-life program I see epochs in 2038, so probably the _offtime is a time offset for time zones, which is not initialized and then translated into the epoch as a random addition or subtraction from the zoneless epoch.

Comment: @Herbert two issues: you're not reading `%s` so you need to set `tm_sec`; also there's a spurious `T` after `%d` which may be interfering with parsing.

Comment: just found that if only date is supplied (i.e. format is `"%Y%m%d"`) then the code run in valgrind spit errors on `mktime`. `memset(&tm, 0, sizeof(tm))` helped to fix it - looks like parts of `tm` are not initialized by `strptime`

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `strptime` does anything with `tm_isdst`, and doesn't handle timezones (well or at all depending on the variation).  `mktime` on the other hand requires `tm_isdst` be set for its calculations so presumably the uninitialized dependency propagates into other code.  In short, you need to decide what to do with timezone handling...