# How do I get warnings for uninitialized member variables? (clang, c++17)

Tags: c++, clang

I understand that c++ variable initialization is extremely complicated and not all compilers 100% conform to the standard, if it's well defined in the first place. Therefore, I want to generate warnings in our whole codebase wherever a variable is not explicitly initialized.

Through my search, I came across these two flags: `-Wmissing-field-initializers` and `-Wconditional-uninitialized`, which look promising. So, I tried the following test code:

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo {
private:
  int bar;

public:
  Foo() {}
  int Bar() { return bar; }
};

int main () {
  Foo foo;
  std::cout << foo.Bar();
  return 0;
}
```

where `Foo::bar` is not initialized anywhere: it's not value initialized, the constructor is user defined and does not initialize `bar`. However, when I compiled it with `clang++ -std=c++17 -Wmissing-field-initializers -Wmissing-field-initializers`, I'm not getting any warnings.

What am I missing here? Thanks.

Comment: "not all compilers 100% conform to the standard"  What do you mean?

Comment: It's worth [looking at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3803153/what-are-primitive-types-default-initialized-to-in-c) first. Try with a non-primitive type.

Comment: `clang++ -std=c++17 -Wmissing-field-initializers -Wmissing-field-initializers` has the same flag twice

Comment: doesn't look like clang supports this https://godbolt.org/z/e9onxaevz

Comment: fwiw, this is the case covered by `-Wmissing-field-initializers` https://godbolt.org/z/5a44KWx3W see also here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21658485/why-do-i-get-warning-missing-initializer-for-member-wmissing-field-initial

Comment: Crank up the optimizer. Often the closer look at the code the optimizer needs shakes loose more diagnostics.

Comment: Hmmmm. Your mileage may vary: https://godbolt.org/z/MM1E4j69j