# How can I remove the warning in GCC 4.6: "missing initializer [-Wmissing-field-initializers]"?

Tags: c, gcc, struct, warnings, glib

The code

```
  GValue value = { 0 };
```

gives the following warning:

> missing initializer [-Wmissing-field-initializers]

I know that's a [GCC bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538943/why-is-the-compiler-throwing-this-warning-missing-initializer-isnt-the-stru), but is there some trick to remove it? It is really not nice see such unreal warnings. But I don't want power off the warning because it will hide real warnings from me too. And sorry, but I can't update my GCC to 4.7 (where looks like it was fixed) version, yet.

Comment: I highly doubt that it is a gcc bug. Could you show us the structure definition of GValue.

Comment: it's just an example; I'm looking for a solution that works for any struct.

Comment: @GajananH I think we can assume that it's a GLib GValue — which means that it has more than one member (and indeed, what worthwhile struct *doesn't* have more than one member?)

Comment: @hobbs: independent how many members the struct have, by using `{0}` all members shall be set to `0`. It's described in the C standard, as you can see in the link in my post.

Comment: There's no bug. According to the standard, a conforming implementation can issue diagnostic messages for any reason whatsoever, including cosmetic reasons, as long as it still accepts valid programs (i.e. it's a warning and not an error). You may disable this specific warning.

Comment: Perhaps I'm splitting hairs, but what version of C or C++ are you compiling against? That could well be a valid warning in, for example, C89 (does anyone even use it anymore?)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `G_VALUE_INIT` to initialize `GValue`-s. Their (private) structure is in `/usr/include/glib-2.0/gobject/gvalue.h` which `#define G_VALUE_INIT` appropriately.

I strongly disagree with your assessment that it is GCC's bug. You ask to be warned if a field is not explicitly initialized with `-Wmissing-field-initializers` and you get the warning you deserve.

Sadly `G_VALUE_INIT` is not documented, but it is here. Code with

```
GValue value = G_VALUE_INIT;
```

There is no universal solution to never get the warning about missing field initialization if `-Wmissing-field-initializers` is asked. When you ask for such a warning, you require the compiler to warn of every incomplete initializers. Indeed, the standard requires than all the non-explicitly initialized `struct` fields be zeroed, and `gcc` obeys the standard.

You could use [diagnostic pragmas](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html) like

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wmissing-field-initializers"
```

But my feeling is that you should code with care, and explicitly initialize all the fields. The warning you get is more a coding style warning (maybe you forgot a field!) than a bug warning.

I also believe that for your own (public) `struct` you should `#define` an initializing macro, if such `struct` are intended to be initialized.

Comment: "I strongly disagree with your assessment that it is GCC's bug" - Agreed. Taking it a step further, initialize everything and let the optimizer discard spurious loads. It gets old tracking down these sorts of bugs because a programmer is trying to be clever (and the memory manager did not serve up a page that was zero'd).

Comment: But it *is* a bug. `{0}` is what's called the "universal zero initializer", and when one uses it, one is **explicitly** initializing all fields to their logical zero. It thus makes no sense for GCC (or Clang, or any other compiler) to emit such a warning on such cases.

Comment: @pwseo Old post, but your statement is not correct. The C language does _not_ treat `{0}` as a special case. There is no such thing as an "universal zero initializer" nor is `{0}` a way to explicitly initialize the whole array/struct. `{0}` simply means: _initialize the very first element to zero, and then let every other member get initialized just as if they had static storage duration, which is done implicitly_. And that is why `{1}` only initializes the first element to 1 and the rest to zero, it works exactly the same.

Comment: @Lundin indeed, `{0}` is not the "universal zero initializer", but `{}` IS the "universal initializer", that will, as per the standard, *always* fill a structure with 0 for fields with no user-defined initializers/no constructor. This language facility is often used because 0 is what the programmer usually wants. Many times this is used with C structures with (obviously) no initializer, and no possibility to add ones. The warning is a (very annoying) GCC bug. Why adding adding non-required, non-useful constraints that will distract the programmer from the actual stuff ?

Comment: @aberaud Huh? Empty initializer lists are not allowed in C, see C11 6.7.9 or read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17589533/is-an-empty-initializer-list-valid-c-code). Also, constructors are of no concern, as there are no constructors in the C language.

Comment: @Lundin Yes, that is the point: C structures (with no constructors/initializers) can be 0-initialized in C++ by using `{}`, and that is totally valid and standard-compliant, because the code is compiled as C++, not C.

Comment: You can use `{0,}` (note the comma) to initialise all fields to zero, but it will choke on some struct layouts. This is as close as C gets to a ‘universal zero initialiser’. If you *really* want a universal zero initialiser, use `memset()` on the struct instance.

Answer (score 11):

You could use:

```
-Wno-missing-field-initializers
```

to inhibit that warning specifically.  Conversely, you could make it into an error with:

```
-Werror=missing-field-initializers
```

Both of these work with GCC 4.7.1; I believe they work with GCC 4.6.x too, but they don't work with all earlier versions of GCC (GCC 4.1.2 recognizes `-Wno-missing-field-initializers` but not `-Werror=missing-field-intializers`).

Obviously, the other way to suppress the warning is to initialize all fields explicitly.  That can be painful, though.

Answer (score 2):

It also appears that using the .field-style of initialization, such as:

```
GValue value = { .somefield = 0 };
```

will cause the compiler to not issue the warning.  Unfortunately if the struct is opaque, this is a non-starter.

Comment: With recent gcc versions, this might no longer be true (I've seen the same warning on a different codebase using a designated initializer like you show, with arm-gcc 8).

Comment: Interesting. IIRC the C standard requires that all unnamed fields be initialized to their zero value with this construct.  So there are no uninitialized fields.

Comment: I believe it *does* zero-initialize, just warns about the missing explicit initializers. Also, it seems this warning only happens for C++, not C code. See also https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=39589