# Use of empty tag struct, compiler claims I'm missing initializer, except I'm not

Tags: c++, gcc, initialization, warnings, compiler-warnings

Okay, I know this is similar to this [Why is the compiler throwing this warning: "missing initializer"? Isn't the structure initialized?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538943/why-is-the-compiler-throwing-this-warning-missing-initializer-isnt-the-stru?lq=1), but surely GCC isn't stupid enough to think I meant to initialize *something which has NO initialization?*.

```
//main.cpp
struct IsNamed{
};

template<typename T>
struct Test{
    int foo;
};
struct Test2 : public Test<double>, public IsNamed{

};
int main(){
    Test2 x;

    Test2 y = Test2{Test<double>{}};
    return 0;
}
```

Here's the output:

```
main2.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main2.cpp:18:35: warning: missing initializer for member 'Test2::<anonymous>' [-Wmissing-field-initializers]
   18 |     Test2 y = Test2{Test<double>{}};
      |                                   ^
main2.cpp:16:11: warning: unused variable 'x' [-Wunused-variable]
   16 |     Test2 x;
      |           ^
main2.cpp:18:11: warning: variable 'y' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
   18 |     Test2 y = Test2{Test<double>{}};
      |
```

The only warning I'm confused about is this " missing initializer for member 'Test2:: " warning.  It makes no sense. There's only one possible value I would need, and I provide it.  Just to prove that it is indeed the inclusion of the empty class in the inheritance chain that is causing this, here's the output if I remove it:

```
main2.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main2.cpp:16:11: warning: unused variable 'x' [-Wunused-variable]
   16 |     Test2 x;
      |           ^
main2.cpp:18:11: warning: variable 'y' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
   18 |     Test2 y = Test2{Test<double>{}};
      |
```

People say just ignore it, but it's not feasible for my project.  I've got *lots* of classes with this error that follow the same tag struct pattern. It's not reasonable to selectively disable this warning (I also find it useful in other circumstances).

How do I get the compiler to stop complaining about this? I should also mention that `Test2{Test<double>{},{}};` would not be an appropriate solution, as I have template code in use where some of the classes do not have this problem, and some do, which means this becomes an error in those circumstances.

EDIT:

Note here is the example CMake used, which included the compiler options:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)
project(test)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11)

add_executable(test main.cpp)
target_include_directories(test
        PRIVATE
        ./
        )
target_compile_options(test PRIVATE
        $<$<OR:$<CXX_COMPILER_ID:Clang>,$<CXX_COMPILER_ID:GNU>>:
        -Wall -Wextra -Wshadow -Wnon-virtual-dtor -pedantic -g -ggdb -O1>)
```

I'm also using mingw64-10.2

Comment: What would happen if you initialized as `Test2 y = Test2{Test<double>{}, IsNamed{}}`?

Comment: Could you add the version of GCC you're using and the exact compiler flags. I'm not seeing this on GCC10.2 with `-Wall`.

Comment: @cigien `-Wextra` does the trick for me.

Comment: The only way to get around this warning on gcc is to define contructors, which of course causes `Test2` to not be an aggregate anymore. You could also file a bug with gcc (clang does not warn for this) but this won't be a fast fix, if it is even considered a bug and fixed at all.

Answer (score 0):

> There's only one possible value I would need, and I provide it

The warning isn't about providing values that you "need". After all, the compiler cannot in general know which values you think are needed.

The warning is about providing **all** initialisers. And there is no initialiser for the other base.

> How do I get the compiler to stop complaining about this?

Provide the missing initialiser:

```
Test2 y = Test2{Test<double>{}, {}};
```

Or just disable the warning. Or use another compiler; Clang appears to not warn in your case for example.

Comment: Just because the compiler does not give a warning it does not mean that the code is OK. Clang has been wrong before...

Comment: @U.W. So has GCC. Just because the compiler gives a warning, doesn't necessarily mean that there is anything wrong with the program.

Comment: True enough! That makes writing software in C++ sooo much fun!! :-)